# Make recall in Harmonic mean twice as important

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, information-retrieval

The formula for the Harmonic Mean is: `(2*Recall*Precision/(1*Recall+Precision)`.

The `2` comes from `(Beta² + 1)` and the `1` comes from `Beta²`. Where `Beta = a factor that indicates the relative importance of recall and precision`.

How do I update the formula so that Recall becomes twice as important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you kind of answered your own question: the Harmonic Mean is the formula you stated with Beta equal to 1, so in order to make recall twice as important as precision, simply set Beta to 2 to obtain:

[image]
[image]